# Wordpress: Custom post type redirecting to homepage

Tags: wordpress, timber

I have created a post type "Team" and it allowed me to go to my site "http://my-site.com/team" and display the team archive page however I turned the team archive page off to create a team page that will pull the team posts in but I decided against it and deleted the page permanently. I turned the team archive on again in my functions.php file and now it redirects me to the homepage all the time.

I have saved the permalinks again using "http://my-site.com/%postname%/" to reset it but it is still not working. "http://my-site.com/?post_type=team" works fine but that's not what I want.

I tried creating an "archive-team.php" file but nothing and I even tried using a new database but that hasn't worked either.

I am using Timber but as the page worked before I don't think there is an issue there.
Anyone got any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Below is my function for registering the team post type

```
function register_team()
{
    $args = [
        'labels' => [
            'name' => 'Team',
            'singlular_name' => 'Team',
        ],
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-users',
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'],
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => 'team',
        ],
    ];

    register_post_type('team', $args);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, test the Team page address with a tool like [this](https://httpstatus.io/). If the status code is anything but 200, you should check the plugins and the .htaccess file.

For example, the yoast or Redirection plugin creates a redirect when a page is deleted.

It may also have a problem with your theme, for example instead of displaying a 404 error, it takes you to the home screen.

The first step is to check the status code and then test it by disabling the plugins and using the default theme (for WordPress twentytwenty and for Woocommerce Storefront).

Comment: Unfortunately this site is local only so I can't use the tool. I don't have any of those plugins though I deactivated all plugins, changed themes and it still redirects me whilst other pages just display a 404 page. I haven't touched the htaccess files but they look to be fine

Comment: To make sure that a redirect is not generated, you can change the slug to **team1** and test whether everything works properly in this case.
Be sure to save the permalink settings once after this.
If this works correctly, an unwanted redirect has been created when you delete this tab.

Comment: Yes that worked, team1 did not redirect. So wordpress has created this redirect somewhere, any idea where?

Comment: OK. You should compare the .htaccess file [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/). Can you search the **team** in the database and see if anything is found? Because I do not know what plugins you had before, it is really hard to help :)

Comment: Yeah my htaccess matches that. The plugins I am using are timber-library, ACF pro and post types order. I have had a look at the database but not much luck, like I said in my question though even creating a new database still causes the issue.

Comment: OK, Have you tested with another browser? Or in private mode?

Comment: Wow, private browser worked. Just cleared my cache and now it's working. There must be something I don't understand about wordpress as to why it did this, any clue?

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way :)

Comment: Good job. This issue has nothing to do with WordPress. One of the cache steps is the **browser cache** and this is related to the user's browser. Good luck.